# Images not loading through HTTPS (working through HTTP)

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https, http-status-code-404

I have a problem with my Wordpress website that had an SSL certificate installed. 
Everything works fine, but the images are not loading.

If I change the https:// at the beginning of the src="" to http:// it works fine.

Same goes when I try to load the image directly into the browser - https gives my e404.

In media gallery on wp-admin everything is broken as well.

How do I make it display everything nicely?

Comment: So you're saying that you had an ssl cert, so everything was setup to use https and now you're trying to revert it to just plain http? In the admin panel make sure under Settings->General that your wordpress url and site address url begin with http. Once you make sure that's done, there could be some changed to your server depending on how the site is being hosted.

Comment: @Ryankozak, no. I'm saying that the images never worked with https. Just throwing the error 404 when I try to reach them by https. I can do it no problem through http.

Comment: Ok, so to clarify, are you able to reach anything else on your site via https? Basically I'm asking that we're sure port 443 is available at all.

Comment: @Ryankozak. Yes, I'm getting js and css without any problems. All the content is displayed nicely, except of the images.

<img src="**https**://domain.com/image.png"> - error 404.
<img src="**http**://domain.com/image.png"> - image file.

Comment: Interesting, if you aren't even able to FTP an image into a directory, and view it, then that means it's an issue beyond WordPress. Are you using apache?

Comment: Have you found the problem? I have a similar problem, https is working, http not.

Comment: @Sven, sorry- unfortunately not.